# Proving $\phi(G)$ is Abelian if $\phi$: $G \to H$ is a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

Question: If $\phi$ : $G \to H$ is a group homomorphism and $G$ is abelian, Prove that $\phi(G)$ is also abelian
 Here is my attempt:
Let $g$,$h\in G$ 
 then $\phi(g)$=$G$ and $\phi(h)$=$G$
$\Rightarrow$ $\phi(gh)$=$\phi(g)\phi(h)$
$\Rightarrow$$g\cdot h$
By using the definition of Abelian, $x\cdot y$ = $y\cdot x$ $\forall$ $x,y\in G$
 $g\cdot h$ = $h\cdot g$ $\forall$ $g,h\in G$
$\Rightarrow$ $\phi(gh)$=$\phi(hg)$
 Am I right? If not then I need help

Comment: What do you mean $\phi(g)=G$?

Comment: You mean $\phi(g)\in H$ and $\phi(h)\in H$?

Comment: I said "Let $g,h\in G$". I am just learning so I was trying to see if it works. If not then I need some help trying to show it

Comment: And what's with the "W.L.O.G." Even trying to reconstruct the train of thought here, there is absolutely no meaningful thing a WLOG could do there.

Comment: Without Lost of Generality

Comment: But, there is nothing to lose generality about. the group $G$ is abelian so $gh=hg$. The WLOG is nonsensical.

Comment: @user296113 that might be the right approach. I see that my initial statement about that is not right

Comment: Try writing your proof _in words_ rather than in symbolism you're not familiar with. Then we can start looking at whether there are places where it would _actually improve the clarity_ of your proof to start using symbols instead of words.

Comment: I am sorry guys for the confusing on here. I took out W.L.O.G part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something went wrong with your notation but you seem to have the right idea. Let $x,y \in \phi (G) $, say $x = \phi (g), y = \phi (h) $ for $g,h \in G $.
To see commutativity, you can compute:
$x \cdot y = \phi(g) \phi(h) = \phi(gh) =\phi(hg) = \phi(h)  \phi(g) = y \cdot x $.

Comment: Oh I see what I did wrong here. These homomorphism proofs be confusing to me sometimes but I am starting to get a hang of it